# Vue.js Application - video element denies streaming on mobile

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mobile, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working on a Vue.js web app that needs to support video streaming. The backend is a Node.js app. It's pulling the videos from an S3 bucket and sending an unbuffered stream to the client. Here's the frontend code:

```
<template>
<div class="page-container">
    <div v-if="currentVideo" class="pageContent">
      <section-head>{{ currentVideo.name }}</section-head>
      <p>{{ currentVideo.description }}</p>
      <video 
        v-if="videoUrl"
        :poster="currentVideo.thumbnail"
        playsinline 
        controls 
        controlslist="nodownload"
        class="stream" 
        type="video/mp4" 
        :key="videoUrl" 
        :src="videoUrl" 
      />
      <section-head>See More</section-head>
      <gallery />
    </div>
    <h1 v-else class="sorry">
      If you're seeing this message, you may have accidently gone to the wrong page.
      Please go to the <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> page.
    </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import sectionHead from '../components/atoms/Header/SectionHead.vue';
import config from '../../config.js';
import gallery from '../components/molecules/Gallery/Gallery.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Stream',
  components: { sectionHead, gallery },
  computed: {
    currentVideo() {
      return this.$store.state.currentVideo;
    },
    videoUrl() {
      return 'https://' + config.currentEnvAPI() + '/stream/' + this.currentVideo.video;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '../styles/_variables.scss';
.page-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  p { 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
  }
}
.stream {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 750px; 
  height: auto;
  outline: none;
  @include tablet {
    width: 650px;     
  }
  @include phone {
    width: 100%;     
  }
}
.sorry {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 120px;
}
</style>
```

And I'm setting and getting the video object from VueX here:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import actions from './actions.js';
import mutations from './mutations.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  videoList: [],
  videoObjects: [],
  loadingData: false,
  currentVideo: null,
  currentGallery: [],
}; 

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
});
```

This is the route that I'm calling on the backend:

```
app.get('/stream/:video', async (req, res) => {
    let videoParams = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: req.params.video,
    };
    S3.getObject(videoParams)
      .on('httpHeaders', function (statusCode, headers) {
          res.set('Content-Length', headers['content-length']);
          res.set('Content-Type', headers['content-type']);
          res.set('Accept-Ranges', headers['accept-ranges']);
          this.response.httpResponse.createUnbufferedStream()
              .pipe(res);
    })
    .send();
});
```

As far as I can tell, this is a good implementation because it works fine on desktop, both locally and deployed. I only have issues on mobile browsers. I've tried both Chrome and Safari on two different iPhones (no access to an Android device). This is all I see  for all of my videos:

[image: Play button strikethrough]

I also took the time to set up an SSL certificate for all of my endpoints, so I know the videos are streaming over https. I was thinking that the size of the videos (between 250 - 550 MB) may be the issue, but I also noticed that even though the element is disabled, the connection still transfers the whole thing.

[image: network tab]

I would think if it was a server side issue that it wouldn't send the whole file, but it does. So wouldn't the issue be client side? I can't figure out why it's not working though. The files are mp4 and I'm sure that they should work because I've tried other links to test with mp4 videos and they've worked. I've changed up the element attributes a lot too. I've tried both with and without playsinline, autoplay, and muted. I've tried having the source element as a child of the video element and that still didn't work. I'm also not getting any console errors, so I can't figure out what the actual problem is and I'm not sure how else I can troubleshoot this.

Comment: how does your end url to mp4 looks like? I had a similar problem because android could not handle special characters, once I did beautify it all worked well.

Comment: So, you brought up a good point I had not considered. All of my urls have dashes or underscores in them. One of them is https://qa-api.nurenproductions.com/stream/UPDATED_2019_REEL_1080.mp4. I decided to see what would happen if I played the videos from the S3 bucket from the AWS app, and one of the videos did actually give me the same icon. The key for that video does have an apostrophe in it, which seems to get converted into a %, so that could definitely be that case with that particular video. The rest of them played fine though from S3 and they just have either underscores or dashes..

Comment: Maybe try sending the content-type header

Comment: I did that here res.set('Content-Type', headers['content-type']);

Answer (score 0):

the h.264 profile of your example file in the comments is "high" but ios safari only supports "base". if you open the file directly in safari, it won't play either.

see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW9